# Import DefinitelyTyped definitions for compilation only

Tags: javascript, typescript, definitelytyped

I have a simple web page as follows which I am using to play a video from Vimeo.

```html
<!-- <!DOCTYPE html> -->
<html>
<body>
    <div id="myVideo"></div>
    
    <script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
    <script src="myScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have just re-written `myScript` in Typescript and in order to get type checking and code-completion working properly, imported the `vimeo__player` definitions from DefinitelyTyped with the following commands:

`npm init`
`npm install --save @types/vimeo__player`

My script now looks as follows with the added import statement at the top.

```js
import * as Vimeo from "vimeo__player"

var options = {
    url: "https://player.vimeo.com/video/440690051",
    width: 640,
    height: 360,
    controls: false,
    autoplay: true
}
var player = new Vimeo.Player("myVideo", options)
```

However, now when I compile this with `tsc myScript.ts` the code won't run in the browser because the following 2 lines are added to `myScript.js`.

```js
exports.__esModule = true;
var Vimeo = require("vimeo__player");
```

How do I tell typescript that `Vimeo` will be provided in my HTML and so not to worry about providing it for me? I.e. just use that import statement for compilation only?

Comment: Instead of `import * as vimeo` you could use `/// <reference types="vimeo__player" />`

Comment: @r3dst0rm If I do this I get an error `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Vimeo'.` when declaring `player`. Can I reference the types as `Vimeo`?

Comment: try `npm install -D @types/vimeo__player`

Comment: @MarcStröbel No luck, the `exports` and `require` lines are still added to `myScript.js` ☹️

Comment: @r3dst0rm I got this working by adding `export as namespace Vimeo;` to the top of the index.d.ts file.